# pigpio monitor GPIO not detecting change correctly

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, pigpio

I am having trouble detecting a level change on pin 16 (or any other pin). My script is as follows:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)

while True:
    if GPIO.input(16)==0:
         print("High")
    else
         print("Low")
    sleep(0.1)
```

After running this code snippet I get "Low" being printed out constantly, even if I connect pin 16 directly to pin 1 (3.3V) using a jumper wire.

To try and figure out why I was not seeing any change I installed pigpio to run `monitor.py` which monitors GPIO for level changes.

After running the script I get:

```
G=14 l=0 d=159303
G=14 l=1 d=5
G=14 l=0 d=90
```

Why is a change being detected on Broadcom GPIO 14 which corresponds to physical pin 8, instead of Broadcom GPIO 23 which corresponds to physical pin 16?

Any pointers on what I could be doing wrong are greatly appreciated.

Comment: GPIO14 is TXD.  Perhaps something is using the serial link or the line is floating.

Comment: Yes, strangely only when I place or remove the jumper wire from the 3.3V do I see GPIO14 changing state. I am also seeing changes in GPIO 8 which is SPI. This started happening when I connected the jumper wire to physical pin 17 instead of physical pin 1. (3.3V)

Comment: I'd set all the GPIO internal pulls so that the GPIO don't float, e.g. `for ((i=2; i<28;i++)); do pigs pud $i d; done`.  I would then do a quick test such as `pigs p 23 60` to start PWM on GPIO23.  Switch off using `pigs p 23 0`.

Comment: Does GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP) use Physical Pin number or BCM Pin Number or WiringPi Pin number?

Comment: @joan thanks for your suggestion. Please excuse this basic question but where should I write the above code you mentioned? Also, Pin number since I specified this in the line before it.

Comment: In a terminal window (should be a GUI option).  pigpio only uses Broadcom numbers so you'd need to convert pin numbers to GPIO numbers.